# What is difference between joining item in two columns by "+" and "||" for SQL

Tags: sql

I usually join the contents in two columns by `column1 + column2` in SQL.

However, I saw one code which combines two columns by `||`. I ran the following code but basically get the exactly same result.

Is there any difference between using `+` and `||`?

```
select CurrentDepartment ||'@' || NameId as Full_ID1, CurrentDepartment+'@'+NameId as Full_ID2
from dmf_dbo.personinfo
```

Comment: `||` is ANSI SQL concatenation. Some products also accept `+`.

Comment: @jarlh, conversely, not all products accept `||`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation operator in Oracle, Postgres and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373238/string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle-postgres-and-sql-server) - not really a duplicate but the answer fits quite well, I think

Comment: In ANSI standard SQL, `||` is used to concatenate strings (varchar) values and `+` to add numbers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do you know why the ISO SQL language design committee decided to use that operator specifically? It seems odd to me that so many modern (post-SQL-92) parts of ISO SQL syntax seem different to almost every other programming language out there for no benefit.

Comment: Maybe because operator overloading wasn't really a thing back in the 80s (or was considered to complicated to implement) so they had to come up with different operators for different data types. But this is really just a wild guess

Comment: `+` is a mathematical operator and makes no sense for character data. How much is green plus Paris?

Comment: @Dai In some old IBM languages (like CL on AS400)  `||` means _concatenate_, `|<` means _rtrim left operand and concatenate_ and `|>` _rtrim left operand and concatenate with a blank character in between_ maybe related

Comment: @StephanBauer Thanks for the link. That's really helpful. And thanks all for the response. It's clear for me now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Operator overloading worked just fine in the 1980s and 1990s.  SQL is a language that is not supposed to confuse people, and `3 + '0'` is totally ambiguous.  Should the answer be `3` or `'30'`.  Best never to have to deal with that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: good to know. It certainly wasn't available with BASIC, COBOL, Pascal and C back then - which is what I was programming with in the 80's ;)